# ListView with two columns, with separate onItemClick - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-gridview

I want to create ListView with 2 columns, something like this:
[image: Img]

So I want on different onItemClick for item1 and item2. I can create this layout with custom adapter, but when i click on first row I get InItemClik for whole row. Can someone tell me how can I do this, or give me some useful links....

**IMPORTANT:**

**This is old question, nowadays this type of layout should be created with [RecycleView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and [LinearLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) for one column only or [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) for more columns.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridView instead of ListView and set it to 2 columns.

Comment: It is sometimes essential for one to use a list view with two subitems per item . An example would be a case where you want layout to have grid but each row have items appear with slide in animation( items per row have synced slide in but each row slide in with delay ) . Here a list view would easily fulfill the task with layout animator. But one more thing, this method has a con of having you adapter objects in couples .

Comment: I agree @RahulVerma although this is a different scenario than the one presented in this question.

Answer (score 3):

add two LinearLayouts(for example) in your custom list xml file and insted of setting OnItemclik listener to list set onClilkListener to these layouts seperately for each.
It should work for you

Comment: Will they scroll together ?

Comment: of course they will they are just two layouts but in same row